# React crashes after updating text input field a second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component where users can enter text into an input field

```
import { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
    const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");

    return (
        <input value={txt} onInput={(e) => { setTxt(() => e.currentTarget.value); }} />
    );
}
```

**Expected behaviour:**

The input field should display the value of `txt`. Whenever the user types the `onInput` event should trigger and update the value of `txt`.

**Actual behaviour**

The code crashes after triggering the `onInput` event for the second time. I get errors like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')
    at <anonymous>:41:36
    at basicStateReducer (<anonymous>:12325:51)
    at updateReducer (<anonymous>:12418:32)
    at updateState (<anonymous>:12654:20)
    at Object.useState (<anonymous>:13444:26)
    at useState (<anonymous>:1114:31)
    at App (<anonymous>:37:51)
    at renderWithHooks (<anonymous>:12163:28)
    at updateFunctionComponent (<anonymous>:15206:30)
    at beginWork (<anonymous>:16602:24)
```

and

```
The above error occurred in the <App> component:

    at App (<anonymous>:37:51)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

```js
onInput={(e) => {
  setTxt(e.currentTarget.value);
}}
```

**Explanation:**

Arrow functions [lexically bind](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-lexical-scope-tutorial/) the `this` value, meaning they inherit the `this` value from their surrounding scope.

In the scenario where you are using `setTxt(() => e.currentTarget.value)`, the arrow function `() => e.currentTarget.value` captures the `e` object from the surrounding scope, which is the `onchange` event handler, but it does not capture the value of `e.target.value` at the moment when the `onChange` event was triggered hence, it gets `e.target` as `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code and it will work fine. Here I have used `setTxt(e.currentTarget.value)` instead of `setTxt(() => e.currentTarget.value);`. Rest of the code is unchanged.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      value={txt}
      onInput={(e) => {
        console.log("e.currentTarget.value", e.currentTarget.value);
        setTxt(e.currentTarget.value);
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using an unnecessary callback inside your input.
try to replace this:

```
<input value={txt} onInput={(e) => { setTxt(() => e.currentTarget.value); }} />
```

to this:

```
<input value={txt} onInput={(e) => { setTxt(e.currentTarget.value); }} />
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `onChange` listner instead of `onInput`

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export function App() {
  const [txt, setTxt] = useState("");

  return (
    <input
      value={txt}
      onChange={(e)=> setTxt(e.currentTarget.value)}
    />
  );
}
```